# Pandas add a summary column that counts values that are not empty strings

Tags: pandas

I have a table that looks like this:

```
    A        B       C
1   foo     
2   foobar   blah   
3
```

I want to count up the non empty columns from A, B and C to get a summary column like this:

```
    A        B       C      sum
1   foo                     1   
2   foobar   blah           2
3                           0
```

Here is how I'm trying to do it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = { 'A' : ["foo", "foobar", ""],
       'B' : ["", "blah", ""],
       'C' : ["","",""]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df)
df['sum'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].notnull().sum(axis=1)
df['sum'] = (df[['A', 'B', 'C']] != "").sum(axis=1)
```

These last two lines are different ways to get what I want but they aren't working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the dataframe with df.head().to_dict()

Comment: I put in my code so you can repo the table

Comment: `df.astype(bool).sum(1)`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, `df.ne('').sum(axis=1)` works for me, same for `(df[['A', 'B', 'C']] != "").sum(axis=1)`

Comment: `(df[['A', 'B', 'C']] != "").sum(axis=1)` work for me

Comment: Thanks for the comments, df['sum'] = (df[['A', 'B', 'C']] != "").sum(axis=1) works for me too. My issue is closed.

Comment: Best to vote to close as no longer reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['sum'] = (df[['A', 'B', 'C']] != "").sum(axis=1)
```

Worked. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner worked for me :)

```
df["sum"] = df.replace("", np.nan).T.count().reset_index().iloc[:,1]
```